Why the unitary dual of a locally compact group is a set?
If $G$ is a locally compact group, the definition of unitary dual of $G$ is the set of all equivalence classes of irreducible unitary representations of $G$, denoted by $\widehat{G}$. But why this is well-defined? If for every Hilbert space $H$, we have a irreducible unitary representations of $G$ on $H$, and they are not unitary equivalence, then the number of the element of $\widehat{G}$ are too many to be a set. So how can we prove $\widehat{G}$ is a set? Use Schur's Lemma?

Doesn't every unitary irrep appear inside $L^2(G)$? Honest question — it's been a long time since I've thought about general locally compact groups.

On the other hand, whether a set or not, the "set" of irreps of a group $G$ is typically not a group. The exception is when $G$ is abelian. In that case, Schur tells you that an irrep is one-dimensional, so there certainly are not more than |{functions from $G$ to $U(1)$}| = $\mathfrak{c}^{|G|}$ many irreps.

@TheoJohnson-Freyd Not every unitary irrep appears in $L^2(G)$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempered_representation

You say "If for every Hilbert space $H$, we have a irreducible unitary representations of $G$ on $H$, and they are not unitarily equivalence" [sic]—but that's an "if".  Why should such a thing happen?

@jack I answered your question below. I should add that one often restricts to $G$'s that are $\sigma$-compact, in which case the Hilbert space can be assumed to be separable.

@GH from MO Thank you! The proof you provided is very helpful!

If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

@GHfromMO Unfortunately for most users it does not turn green anymore.

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე Sorry to hear that. At any rate, I will keep asking :-)

This is an immediate cardinality argument. It holds for $G$ an arbitrary topological group, by the way.

@TheoJohnson-Freyd You are probably thinking of a compact $G$, then every unitary irrep appears in $L^2(G)$. It might help to observe that no unitary irrep of $\mathbb{R}$ appears in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (no sine wave is $L^2$). This provides a little false hope, because all unitary irreps are weakly contained in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ -  every character of $\mathbb{R}$ can be weakly approximated by an $L^2$ function. But this is not true for all $G$, non-amenable groups are exactly the groups $G$ where not every unitary irrep is weakly contained in $L^2(G)$.

Let $\pi$ be an irreducible unitary representation of $G$ on the Hilbert space $H$. For every nonzero vector $v\in H$, the closure of $\pi(G)v$ is $H$. Hence $\dim H\leq|G|$, and there are only set many choices for $H$ up to isomorphism. Once we fix $H$, there are only set many choices for $\pi$, because $\pi$ maps $G$ into $U(H)$. So the unitary equivalence classes of such $\pi$ form a set, and this set is the unitary dual of $G$.
